# How can I use jquery to change with a value of select option the color of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of a submit button after a selected option is clicked, for example: buyer's of a sport car click on one of the following options:
1. Ferrari
2. Lamborghini
3. Porsche

Eccording the selected car from the selected option should the submit button turn the color into green. How can I use the jquery library and the code for this?

I tried the following codes, but it don't work!

The jquery code:

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.cars').bind(function(){
    $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor'); 
    });
    });`
```

The html code:

```
`<select class="cars">
      <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
      <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
      <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
    </select> 
      <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Go to Car">`
```

The CSS code:

`.SubmitButton {width:150px;}
.ButtonColor {color:green;}`

My code dosen't work - have someone an idee how can I fixed it?

Comment: `$('select.cars').change(function(){`

Comment: Don't work with .change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select.cars').change(function(){
        $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor'); 
        });
    });
----------------- OR--------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select.cars').on( 'change', function(){
        $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor'); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need change bind to change event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.cars').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'lamborghini'){
         $('.SubmitButton').removeClass('ButtonColor1');
         $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor');
      }else if($(this).val() == 'porsche'){
      $('.SubmitButton').removeClass('ButtonColor');
         $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor1');
      }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("select.cars").val() == ""){
        $(".SubmitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    $('select.cars').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'lamborghini'){
         $(".SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
         $('.SubmitButton').removeClass('ButtonColor1');
         $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor');
         
      }else if($(this).val() == 'porsche'){
       $(".SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.SubmitButton').removeClass('ButtonColor');
         $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor1');
      }
      else if($(this).val() == 'ferrari'){
       $(".SubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.SubmitButton').removeClass('ButtonColor');
         $('.SubmitButton').addClass('ButtonColor2');
      }
      else if($("select.cars").val() == ""){
        $(".SubmitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
    
    var mstart = $("select.cars option").filter(function() { return $(this).text().indexOf("M") === 0; })
    
    
});

Updated:

If you want to find option start with M you can use this 

var mstart = $("select.cars option").filter(function() { return $(this).text().indexOf("M") === 0; })
```

```css
.SubmitButton {width:150px;}
.ButtonColor {color:green;}
.ButtonColor1 {color:red;}
.ButtonColor2 {color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cars">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
      <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
      <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
      <option value="porsche">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="porsche">Mazda</option>
    </select> 
      <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Go to Car">
```

Comment: Great. Thank's a lot. Can I ask you one thing more: if I want to disabled the button if i don't select any car and remove the disabled option when i select a car - how can I do this?

Comment: I updated answer, you can use attr("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: I want to ask you a little question. If I want to have more car manifuctures with the start character "M" for example, Mercedes, Mazda or with the character "F" like Ferrari, Ford, Fiat how can I discribe this with a CSS attribute [option value^="f"] on val() == 'ferrari'). I don't want to write the whole name of a car manifacturer, but just the first character like for example "f" or "m". Who can I do this, with the CSS attribute I write above i didn't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Are you there? Can you write the answear!

Comment: I updated answer, your requirement need handle by jquery because CSS can not read value of option tag